# Angular table edit inline pagination

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap

ayudenme porfavor tengo un error al querer poner paginarion (dirpagination) a mi tabla con edit inline angular js, no se porque me sale este error ya que en mis otras tablas de solo mostrar data esta todo bien, pero en esta tabla estoy con un metodo editable llamando a un ng-include.
esta es mi tabla en html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-bordered">
    <tr>
    <th>

        <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='FirstName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
            First Name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'FirstName'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
        </a>

    </th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Hire Date</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Postal Code</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Opciones</th>

    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr dir-paginate="employee in Employees  | filter: search | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | itemsPerPage :25" ng-include="getTemplate(employee)">
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">

                <td>{{employee.FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.HireDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</td>
                <td>{{employee.Address}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.City}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.PostalCode}}</td>
                <td>{{showCountry(employee.CountryID) }}</td>     
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editEmployee(employee)">Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee)">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </script>
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
                <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.FirstName class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.LastName class="form-control input-sm" /></td>


                <td><datepicker date-format="dd-MM-yyyy"><input type="text" ng-model="employee.HireDate" class="form-control input-sm"  /></datepicker></td>

                <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.Address class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.City class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.PostalCode class="form-control input-sm" /></td>

                <td>
                    <select ng-model="employee.CountryID" @*ng-selected="employee.CountryID" ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList"*@ class="form-control input-sm">

                        <option ng-repeat="value in CountryList"
                                ng-selected="employee.CountryID == value.CountryID"
                                value="{{value.CountryID}}">
                             {{value.CountryName}}
                        </option>

                    </select>

                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateEmployee(employee)">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="reset($index)">Cancel</button>
                </td>
            </script>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<dir-pagination-controls max-size="5"
                         direction-links="true"
                         boundary-links="true">
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

aqui mi controller :

angular.module("MyApp", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','720kb.datepicker', 'chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'ngAnimate'])

```
.config(function (cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
      cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = true;
  })
.controller('PartGrider', function ($scope, EmployeeService, $timeout, cfpLoadingBar) {

    $scope.orderByField = 'FirstName';
    $scope.reverseSort = false;

    $scope.Employees = [];
    $scope.employeeData = {};
    $scope.selected = {};



    $scope.CountryList = null;

    $scope.open = function ($event, employee) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        employee.isOpen = true;
    };


    $scope.showCountry = function (data) {

        var obj = null;

        angular.forEach($scope.CountryList, function (val) {

            if (val.CountryID == data) {
                obj = val.CountryName;
            }
        });

        return obj;     
    }


    EmployeeService.GetCountry().then(function (d) {

        $scope.CountryList = d.data;



    }, function (error) {

        alert("Error");

    });



    EmployeeService.GetEmployeesList().then(function (d) {

        $scope.Employees = d.data;

    }, function (error) {

        alert("Error!!!!");

    });

    $scope.actualizaMatriz = function () {

        EmployeeService.GetEmployeesList().then(function (d) {

            $scope.Employees = d.data;
        }, function (error) {

            alert("Error!!!!");

        });

    }



    $scope.addEmployeetoDB = function () {

        $scope.employeeData = {
            FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
            Address: $scope.Address,
            City: $scope.City,


        };

        EmployeeService.AddEmployee(employeeData).then(function (d) {

            alert(d);

        })

        EmployeeService.GetEmployeesList().then(function (d) {

            $scope.Employees = d.data;
        }, function (error) {

            alert("Error!!!!");

        });

    };






    $scope.deleteEmployee = function (employee) {

        $scope.employeeData = {
            FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
            Address: $scope.Address,
            City: $scope.City,

        };

        EmployeeService.DeleteEmployee(employee).then(function (d) {

            alert(d);
            $scope.actualizaMatriz();

        });

        EmployeeService.GetEmployeesList().then(function (d) {

            $scope.Employees = d.data;
        }, function (error) {

            alert("Error!!!!");

        });

    };


    $scope.updateEmployee = function (employee) {

        $scope.employeeData = {
            FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
            Address: $scope.Address,
            City: $scope.City,

        };

        EmployeeService.UpdateEmployee(employee).then(function (d) {
            alert(d);
            $scope.reset();
            $scope.actualizaMatriz();
        });
    };


    $scope.getTemplate = function (employee) {
        if (employee.EmployeeID === $scope.selected.EmployeeID) {
            return 'edit';
        }
        else return 'display';
    };


    $scope.reset = function (index) {
        $scope.Employees[index] = $scope.selected;
        $scope.selected = {};
    }


    $scope.editEmployee = function (employee) {
        $scope.selected = angular.copy(employee);
    };


    $scope.start = function () {
        cfpLoadingBar.start();
    };

    $scope.complete = function () {
        cfpLoadingBar.complete();
    }


    // fake the initial load so first time users can see it right away:
    //$scope.start();
    //$scope.fakeIntro = true;
    //$timeout(function () {
    //    $scope.complete();
    //    $scope.fakeIntro = false;
    //}, 750);



})

.factory('EmployeeService', function ($http, $q) {

    var fac = {};

    fac.GetCountry = function () {

        return $http.get('/Data/GetCountries')

    }


    fac.GetEmployeesList = function () {

        return $http.get('/Data/GetEmployeeList')
    }


    fac.AddEmployee = function (data) {


        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({


            url: '/Data/AddEmployee',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }

        }).success(function (d) {

            defer.resolve(d);

        }).error(function (e) {

            alert("Error!!!!");
            defer.reject(e);
        });

        return defer.promise;


    }



    fac.DeleteEmployee = function (data) {

        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http({


            url: '/Data/DeleteEmployee',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }

        }).success(function (d) {

            defer.resolve(d);

        }).error(function (e) {

            alert("Error!!!!");
            defer.reject(e);
        });

        return defer.promise;

    }

    fac.UpdateEmployee = function (data) {

        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({


            url: '/Data/UpdateEmployee',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }

        }).success(function (d) {

            defer.resolve(d);

        }).error(function (e) {

            alert("Error!!!!");
            defer.reject(e);
        });

        return defer.promise;

    }







    return fac;

})

 .filter('active', function () {

     return function (input) {
         if (input == '1')
             return 'Yes';
         else
             return 'No';
     };
 })

.filter('dateFilter', function () {

    return function (item) {

        if (item != null) {
            return new Date(parseInt(item.substr(6)));
        }
        return "";
    }

});
```

el error es q no me muestra nada en la tabla y en la consola de chrome me sale esto:

```
angular.js:11655 TypeError: Cannot read property 'EmployeeID' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.getTemplate (PartGrid.js:157)
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12404)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch (angular.js:12813)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14300)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1455)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4203)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1453)
    at bootstrap (angular.js:1473)
```

segun entiendo es el error en el metodo getTemplate de mi controller, no se q hacer en este caso.

Comment: Tu error es por que estas ejecutando un `ng-include` cuando se carga la pagina, en ese punto no hay un `$scope.selected` por eso te manda el error al querer comparar algo que aun no existe.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta , en ese caso que puedo hacer para usar ese ng-include

Comment: Con ng-repeat funciona todo bien